# hide some area (sidebar/footer) from googlebot. causing any SEO problem?

Tags: seo, googlebot

For example, I have a product page

```
http://www.myshop.com/product/iphone.html
```

in this page, normal users will see:

- content area (about the iPhone itself)
- sidebar links (links to other products: HTC, Samsung)
- footer area (about the seller)

but *googlebot* only see content area. I hide sidebar links and footer area from *googlebot*.

I do this so that if someone *google* '`htc site:myshop.com`', he/she will not see that iPhone page in search results.

Will this cause any SEO problem? (I'm afraid google consider this as cheating their *googlebot* and punish the website)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bad idea to hide elements for google, google is smart and you could definitely get punished for this.

Read more here: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66355